# VS 2012 - local work items/to do list?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I'd like to setup some sort of work item tracking that I don't necessarily have to push up to the server, but can if I want to. I would think of this as a To Do list or similar to work items in TFS. Anybody know of how this can be accomplished?

Comment: A simple notepad text file on your desktop?

Comment: Ha, very funny. The reason I want it in VS is so I can attach it such to-dos to files/sections of code and immediately see them in context instead of having to do... exactly what you just said. Also, as I mentioned, it would be good if I could commit such items to TFS or if it integrates with TFS.

Comment: In that case the //TODO items seem to be your friend :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put //TODO: blah comments in code you can view them all by opening the Tasks window (from the View Menu).

It will automatically find all // TODO: comments and give you the list of them.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I wasn't sure if there's a better solution. Is that pretty much all VS can do in this department? Perhaps I should stick with TFS work? The only thing I don't like about TFS work is that everything has to be committed - I like to add these locally sometimes before committing. Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure what you envision doing with TFS work items.  WI's aren't tied to code, or specific lines of code.  They can be linked to a changeset, but that's it.

Comment: Hmm. I thought that you could attach work items to a file/section of code.